# Nested animated routes in React Router V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, framer-motion

I'm really struggling to implement something in React Router Version 6, that was relatively straight-forward in Version 5.

I'd like to not only animate between routes (which is now finally possible in Version 6 due to a [recent commit](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/pull/7937) to the library), but also to animate nested routes. Think sliding pages, within sliding pages.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/animated-nested-routes-demo-react-router-v6-f321if?file=/src/index.tsx) is a CodeSandbox with what I have so far.

I'm using Framer Motion's [`AnimatePresence`](https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/) to detect exit animations. But React Router wants to re-animate the parent route, even if just the nested route has changed.

As you can see in the [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/animated-nested-routes-demo-react-router-v6-f321if?file=/src/index.tsx), the routes are animating okay, but when clicking the "Next nested page" link, it also re-animates the whole page, which is not what's desired. What I'd like is for Page 1 to stay static while its' nested route animates. Obviously, when you click "Next page", the whole page ***should*** animate (moving from Page 1 to Page 2). But I can't seem to have my cake and eat it.

[image]

Has anyone been able to do this? Grumblings in the library and on the wider web are indicating that this may be impossible currently?

Answer (score 5):

The reason why `AnimatePresence` is re-animating the parent route upon child navigation is because of the `key` prop. When the `key` changes, React treats it as an entirely new component. Since the `location.key` will always change when a route changes, passing `location.key` to both `Routes` components will trigger the route animations every time.

The only solution I can think of is to manage the keys for both `Routes` components manually. If you change the URL structure to make the base route path `/page1`, the solution is pretty simple:

[Forked Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/animated-nested-routes-demo-react-router-v6-forked-lxf1bf)

To keep your current URL structure, you'll need to create a key for the top-level `Routes` comp that changes when navigating from `/` to `/page2`, but doesn't change when navigating from `/` to `/nested1` or from `/nested1` to `/nested2`.